# How to add some text between source code and results exports to PDF?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Whenver I want to export a source code block with it's results, I want to add some text in-between, e.g. "Output:", because otherwise is very hard for the reader to understand where the program ends and the output begins - how do I achieve adding "Output:" in-between?

Example:

```
* Test
  #+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :exports both
i = 5
print i
i = i + 1
print i

s = '''This is a multi-line string.
This is the second line.'''
print s
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  : 5
  : 6
  : This is a multi-line string.
  : This is the second line.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name your source code block. Then, and only then, you can put your results part wherever you want, even before the source code block.

EDITED (add ECM):

```
#+name: my-block
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(message "hello")
#+end_src

I can put paragraphs here...

#+results: my-block
: hello
```

Comment: Maybe we should put this in the FAQ.

Comment: Could you add MWE to demonstrate the solution?